# Change DocumentRoot by URL path

Tags: apache, virtualhost

How do I change the DocumentRoot according to the URL path using VirtualHost?

I want this:

- `example.com` to serve `/var/www`
- `example.com/2` to serve `/var/www2`

I'm using Alias, which serves the correct directory, but doesn't change the 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' server variable.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www"
    ServerName example.com
    Alias /2 "/var/www2"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why should you change DocumentRoot? Your Virtual Host code should work and redirect to /var/www2 if apache has permissions on the folder.

Comment: Because I use the DOCUMENT_ROOT server variable on several occasions in my code. I could fake this variable, but i hope there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: From the Apache documentation : `The DocumentRoot directive is set in your main server configuration file (httpd.conf) and, possibly, once per additional Virtual Host you create.` So if you set it once, you cannot modify it in the same vhost, at least that is what I am understanding from their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your document root, the top-level directory that Apache looks at to find content to serve, will be set to individual directories under the /var/www directory. You will create a directory in this path for your virtual hosts. Like this:

> sudo mkdir -p /var/www/**www1**

> sudo mkdir -p /var/www/**www2**

Then in your virtual host config you will do the follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/www1"
   ServerName example.com
   Alias /2 "/var/www/www2"
</VirtualHost>
```